How do I fix NVIDIA SMI failing after a clean install of drivers and container toolkit on Ubuntu?
I'm using NVIDIA driver 535 on an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server. After purging and reinstalling all NVIDIA-related packages, including the NVIDIA Container Toolkit, nvidia-smi fails to run. Has anyone encountered this, and what are the best practices to resolve this?

This issue can be a mismatch between the installed NVIDIA driver and the toolkit in most cases. You can check both the driver and toolkit versions compatibility. After purging your previous installations (you can check existing packages with dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia and purge all nvidia components with sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*', follow these steps:

Use sudo ubuntu-drivers list --gpgpu (for servers) devices to list/provide the recommended driver. It will provide a list similar like this one

nvidia-driver-470
nvidia-driver-470-server
nvidia-driver-535
nvidia-driver-535-open
nvidia-driver-535-server
nvidia-driver-535-server-open
nvidia-driver-550
nvidia-driver-550-open
nvidia-driver-550-server
nvidia-driver-550-server-open


Run sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu to automatically install your recommended driver or specify
sudo ubuntu-drivers install --gpgpu nvidia:535-server with
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-535-server

Install the NVIDIA Container Toolkit as follow in your bash terminal


sudo apt-get update \
    && sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit-base

Confirm ctk version
nvidia-ctk --version

Setup the package repository and the GPG key:
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) \
      && curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/gpgkey | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg \
      && curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/$distribution/libnvidia-container.list | \
            sed 's#deb https://#deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nvidia-container-toolkit-keyring.gpg] https://#g' | \
            sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.list

Install the Container Toolkit with
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-container-toolkit

Configure the docker runtime for ctk
sudo nvidia-ctk runtime configure --runtime=docker

Reboot docker after configuring the runtime
sudo systemctl restart docker

Then you can test with a CUDA base container (20.04 base works on 22.04)
sudo docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.6.2-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi


Reboot your system, and run nvidia-smi to verify the status.

Ensure your kernel modules are loaded by running lsmod | grep nvidia. If you still run into issues, check the /var/log/syslog for any additional errors.
References:

https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation#the-recommended-way-ubuntu-drivers-tool
https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/1.13.5/install-guide.html#setting-up-nvidia-container-toolkit
https://thelinuxcode.com/clean-install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-22-04-lts/

Most of this can be found on the referenced links. Let me know your thoughts and suggestions around this!
